# How to Enable Virtualization Windows 10, InsydeH20

Tags: windows-10, virtualization

I am trying to enable my virtualization on my Windows 10 machine with no avail. I need this for android development.

Here are some specs:

- Windows 10 x64 home
- Intel Core i5
- InsydeH20 BIOS - virtualization is ENABLED
- According to Speccy, virtualization is supported but not enabled

I have tried everything I can think of. I have read other messages and other forums and nothing seems to help. Many times the question pertains to a VM or virtual box, but this is a stand alone computer with no other virtualization on it.

Some messages say that Hyper-V is needed, but Hyper-V is not supported with windows 10 home. If I need it, I can upgrade, but I don't want to do that if it's not needed.

Anyone have some suggestions?

---

Error Messages:

In Android Studio I am told that HAX kernel module is not installed. However, this is, in fact, installed per the Android Studio.

[image]

When I try to run the installer manually, I am told

> This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, bt Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on.

Comment: Error messages please or at least some description of the problem you're facing

Comment: To do what you want, you do indeed, need Hyper-V.  `VT-x` is reported as being disabled because of the version of Windows you are running.  VMWare or Virtual Box would detect it as being enabled though.

Comment: @Ramhound - So, you recommend upgrading to pro? It certainly couldn't hurt... but I don't want to purchase it if I don't need to. (I'm a student at the moment).

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 10?

Comment: So HAX shows that it is installed via the SDK, but did you actually run the HAX exe? `your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe`

Comment: @Ramhound 64 bit

Comment: @DrZoo - Yes I did. The second error message "This computer meets the requirements for HAXM..." is from the exe

Comment: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838 What is the status of Execute Disable Bit and Enhanced Halt State?

Comment: The reason you are running in trouble is by default Android Studio is  expecting the Hyper-V feature to be enabled basically.

Comment: @DrZoo - Both are Yes. The Intel VT-x with extended page tables is also Yes.

From what Ramhound is saying, I am guessing I need to just upgrade to pro.

Comment: Does your CPU have like a "panel" where you can edit settings? Also is this a laptop or what?

Comment: @DrZoo - I don't know of any panel.
The computer is an Inspiron 15R 5537
Service Tag: 39HT302

Comment: My only other guess would be to go into the `Advanced Settings` to ensure that the virtualization/vt-x option is enabled. To get to `Advanced Settings` Open settings and click on the update and security icon > click on recovery on the left side > click on restart now under advanced startup > after the PC restarts click on troubleshoot > click on advanced options > click on UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: @DrZoo is there anywhere else to look at the UEFI settings? Going into advanced does not show that. 
If not, that's fine... I will probably just upgrade to pro anyway. I do appreciate all of your help, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head on the keyboard multiple times with no avail, I finally figured out what the problem was.

First, let me say that the issue is NOT Hyper-V. If you are running into this issue and you think that you need Hyper-V (as I did), you don't. In fact, installing Hyper-V made the entire process worse. Instead of getting an error that the VT-x wasn't turned on, you get an error that the computer is incompatible for virtualization. So, don't waste your time or money (windows home does not have Hyper-v, you have to upgrade to pro to get it).

The solution was actually pretty simple, but I would have never thought of it on my own. I ran across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581854/enabling-intel-virtualization-vt-x-without-option-in-bios) just out of curiosity on what people would do without the virtualization option in BIOS and noticed the settings for Avast (which I happen to use).

Disable

```
 Settings > Troubleshooting > Enable hardware-assisted virtualization
```

Restart and Viola! VT-x is now turned on HAXM installed successfully.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I sadly sort of hinted that other virtualization software packages ( VMWare and VirtualBox ) would have worked also.  This was actually my first comment, and only mentioned Android Studio and Hyper-V connection because historical connection between the Intel components Hyper-V.  Had you gone to say Virtual Machine and attempt to run a 64-bit VM, you would have been told virtualization was also turned off, this would have likely allowed us to ask about any other software that might have had hardware virtualization enabled already.

Comment: @Ramhound I am very grateful for all of your suggestions and the time you took to help me. I may have worded my question poorly, but I specifically did not mention VM or Virtual machine because I thought that would lead people to believe I was running a VM. I am not. This is a stand alone computer. 

My apologies for omitting information that may have helped. That was never my intent. But again, thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: You are running a VM, it's an android VM, hence the need for the virtualization extension

Comment: @Ramhound.... I didn't think of it that way. Good point. I guess I should have been more specific.

Answer (score -2):

For android developement , you dont require a virtual box and VMWare or any kind of virtualization. 
You have an Android Virtual Device (AVD) to run android on windows.
Try out Android studio .

If you are developing using Android studio or using an AVD with eclipse
and have problems loading the Android Virtual Device(AVD) then
view this blog it will help you get started
riantech007.blogspot.com

Comment: I am using android studio. I have added the error messages I am getting.